# How can I get the current window size on Android before API 30?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app which needs to know the available size of its window (in real pixels), allowing for any navigation bar that may be present, and preferably also allowing for the possibility that it may be running in multiwindowed mode, in order to do its layout. So I can't wait until its top level window has been laid out and then ask its size.

(Actually I think that there is a *really ugly* solution which involves initially creating an empty layout. Waiting until the first call to `onDraw` occurs and posting a `Runnable` from it, where the `Runnable` does the real layout and calls `invalidate()`.)

With API 30 and later I can call
`getSystemService(WindowManager.class).getCurrentWindowMetrics()`

but navigation bars first appeared well before then, and I want my app to work on devices with earlier versions of Android.

Is there a reasonably clean way of doing this before API 30?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/window may have some backwards-compatible options for you.

Comment: The ugly solution does work: I just implemented it, except that I overrode `onLayout()` instead of `onDraw(`), and the `Runnable` calls a `resume()` method which does what `onResume()` would normally do. The actual `onResume()` just sets up the dummy layout. and when it returns the framework will in due course get around to updating the screen and ask the dummy layout to do `onLayout()`.